# How can I suggest places while user is typing?

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3

All I want to do for now in my React Native App is having a textbox that displays a list of suggested places accordind with user info. The same like Uber uses to suggest addresses or places.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use another API which you can use to query matching names as user types and suggest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check:

```
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete
```

It is really easy, you only have to install with `npm`, get an API key for places and follow the example in the example of the GitHub's repository.

And that's it. Really hope it can help you